Running a test using foundry getting error
can anybody please tell me why I am getting this error despite having a test file?
No tests found in project! Forge looks for functions that starts with `test`. Error: No tests to run

As @ZartajAfser has mentioned in the answer, your test function should start with test prefix (all lowercase). So, in your FundMe.t.sol file, just change the function name from TestDemo to testDemo.


Add more details to your question first, folder structure, test file, command you tried running
Check the following:


Make sure you have a folder, named test, inside which, the test file should be.
Your test contract should inherit the  "forge-std/Test.sol";.
The test function should start with test prefix. For example:

 function ownerCheck() external {
       //Your test
  }

It should be:
function testownerCheck() external {
       //Your test
}

Please add more details about your project, if you have already checked all these.

I have checked and everything seems fine, I wish I could give you a screenshot.

Don't wish, just add the test file, folder structure/ github links or any information about your environment. You can edit the question.

I tried doing everything from scratch and noticed that the foundry was not allowing me to write my test despite deleting the default counter.sol in the src file and counter.t.sol in the test file I am getting this error.
'''Error (6275): Source "src/Counter.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "/home/kwasako/foundry-f24/foundry-fund-me-f24
